# If self realization or Kaivalya Mukti is only way to escape the rebirth cycle then why there is a concept of other types of Muktis or Mokshas?

Tags: mukti

There are four types of Muktis, Salokya, Samipya, Saroopya and Kaivalya  . Then if a person gets Salokya or Samipya or Saroopya mukti will he born again? Or only Kaivalya mukti let's you escape from rebirth cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salokya,Sameepya,Sarupya and Sayujya are 4 sorts of liberation, occuring  as a result of the nature of saguna upasana (meditation).The venerable Upasakas soul leaves through brahmarandra(crown of the head) via sushmna canal, As said in Gita 8.26, such a great soul travels through archiradi marga(path of light) to Brahmaloka , **and there is no return(no rebirth)** (probably at their will, they may choose appear here in some cases)..but in the case of kaivalya mukti there is no question of departure through any channel . where Prana dissolves right away escaping rebirth cycle..

Attainment of Brahmaloka yields Krama mukti

> Kramamukti - It is called as gradual liberation. Kramamukti is achieved by the performance of one’s ordained duties coupled with contemplation on the Vedic deities . It takes to the Arcīrādimārga and goes to Brahmaloka.Final liberation results from the dissolution of the Brahmaloka at the end of the cycle of the creation.
> Swami Harshananda

PS *In the case of a normal person, the soul may depart through any Nadi ,and would be born helplessly, depending on its past karma.. there is no escape from samsaric cycle,...*
Shiva Gita
[image]

Shiva Gita(chap 13) , Shivanada lahari(28),, Bhagavad Gita, Brahma Sutra has the references

> [BG 8.26](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=8&field_nsutra_value=26&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etgb=1&setgb=1) The bright and the dark paths of the world are verily thought to be eternal; by the one (the bright path) a man goes not to return and by the other (the dark path) he returns.

**BrahmaSutra Adyaya 4**

> The attainment of Brahmaloka by the worshippers of the Saguna Brahman has been treated in the last Adyaya 
> **Adhikarana2. IX: (Sutra 17)** The soul of the knower of the Saguna Brahman comes to the heart at the time of departure and thence goes out through the Sushumna. The soul of the ignorant man goes out by means of some other Nadi.
> **Adhikarana 2.VI: (Sutras 12-14)** The Pranas of a knower of the Nirguna Brahman do not depart from the body at departure. *(Kaivalya mukti)*
> **Adhikarana 4.VII: (Sutras 17-22)** The released soul which has attained Brahmaloka has all the lordly powers except the power of creation, etc. **There is no return to this world for these released souls**
> *Adhikarana 4.IV: (Sutras 8-9)* The soul which has attained the Saguna Brahman, effects its desires be mere will.
> *Adhikarana 4.V: (Sutras 10-14)* A released soul which has attained Brahmaloka can exist with or without a body according to its liking.
> *Adhikarana VI: (Sutras 15-16)* The released soul which has attained the Saguna Brahman can animate several bodies at the same time.
> Swami Sivananda

`why there is a concept of other types of Muktis or Mokshas?`

BG says that kaivalya exceedingly difficult for an embodied . Although it is inferred to be improbable, it doesn't say it is impossible .

> For those whose minds are attached to the unmanifest, the path of realization is full of tribulations. Worship of the unmanifest is exceedingly difficult for embodied beings.(BG 12.5 Translation Swami Mukundananda)